# Toggling two events on one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm trying to add some functionality to be able to edit comments inline. So far it's pretty close, but I'm experiencing issues trying to trigger a second event. It works the first time, but after that, fails.

```
$(function() {
    var $editBtn = $('.js-edit-comment-btn');
    var clicked = false;

    $editBtn.on('click', $editBtn, function() {
        clicked = true;
        var $that = $(this);
        var $form = $that.closest('.js-edit-comment');
        var $commentTextBody = $that.closest('div').find('.js-comment-body');
        var commentText = $commentTextBody.text();
        var $editableText = $('<textarea />');

        if ($that.text() === 'Save Edits') {
            $that.text('Saving...').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $that.text('Save Edits').attr('alt', 'Save your edits');
        }
        
        // Replace div with textarea, and populate it with the comment text
        var makeDivTextarea = function($editableText, commentText, $commentTextBody) {
            $editableText.val(commentText);
            $commentTextBody.replaceWith($editableText);
            $editableText.addClass('gray_textarea js-edited-comment').width('100%').css('padding', '4px').focus();
        };
        makeDivTextarea($editableText, commentText, $commentTextBody);


        var saveEdits = function($that, $editableText) {
            $that.on('click', $that, function() {
                if (clicked) {
                    var comment = $that.closest('div').find('.js-edited-comment').val();

                    $editableText.wrap('<div class="js-comment-body" />').replaceWith(comment);
                    $that.text('Edit').attr('alt', 'Edit Your Comment').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#output').append('saved');
                    clicked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };
        saveEdits($that, $editableText);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/ArXWM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** for your working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8P6uz/

`clicked=true` was the issue :)) I have rectified another small thing. `i.e. $('#output') is set to empty before appending another saved hence text **saved** will only appear once.`

*small note:* If I may suggest use Id of the button or if there are many edit buttons try using `this` which you already i reckon; I will see if I can write this more cleaner but that will be sometime latter-ish but this should fix your issue. :) enjoy!

**Jquery Code**

```
$(function() {
    var $editBtn = $('.js-edit-comment-btn');
    var clicked = false;

    $editBtn.on('click', $editBtn, function() {
        clicked = true;
        var $that = $(this);
        var $form = $that.closest('.js-edit-comment');
        var $commentTextBody = $that.closest('div').find('.js-comment-body');
        var commentText = $commentTextBody.text();
        var $editableText = $('<textarea />');

        if ($that.text() === 'Save Edits') {
            $that.text('Saving...').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $that.text('Save Edits').attr('alt', 'Save your edits');
        }

        // Replace div with textarea, and populate it with the comment text
        var makeDivTextarea = function($editableText, commentText, $commentTextBody) {
            $editableText.val(commentText);
            $commentTextBody.replaceWith($editableText);
            $editableText.addClass('gray_textarea js-edited-comment').width('100%').css('padding', '4px').focus();
        };
        makeDivTextarea($editableText, commentText, $commentTextBody);


        var saveEdits = function($that, $editableText) {
            $that.on('click', $that, function() {
                if (clicked) {
                    var comment = $that.closest('div').find('.js-edited-comment').val();

                    $editableText.wrap('<div class="js-comment-body" />').replaceWith(comment);
                    $that.text('Edit').attr('alt', 'Edit Your Comment').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#output').text("");
                    $('#output').append('saved');
                    clicked = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };
        saveEdits($that, $editableText);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Well that's still the same issue. The second event keeps bubbling. I tried on click of it (the second event handler for the button) by adding e.stopPropagation() but that didn't solve it. Basically the reason why I was appending "saved" to it was to illustrate this example. Guess I should have been more clear above.

Comment: @bob_cobb Hiya Cooleos whats the second event? I thought earlier version of jsfiddle was not even working but now you cant edit and save! + the append save wasn't clear. Please let me know if I am not getting appoint and sorry if I am not getting and sound bit thick but surely can help you out :) cheers man!